# how to show files from directory and all subdirectories?

Tags: php, photo, photo-gallery

I'm working on my photo gallery when user can upload photos and also choose a category. My categories are subdirectories in `images/`. When user doesn't choose a category then photos are stored in `images/`. I want to display all photos (from all categories and other) in gallery but now I manage to show only these without category. Can someone help me?
Here's fragment of my php code

```
 $fo=opendir("images");

        if ($dh = opendir("images")){

        $count = 1;

        while($file=readdir($fo)){


            if($file!="" && $file!="." && $file!=".."){
                        $image_path = "images/".$file;

                if(!is_dir($image_path)){
    ?>
                      <div class="gallery"> 

                <a href="<?= $image_path; ?>">
                <img src="<?= $image_path; ?>">
```

I tried to list all subdirectories

```
$directories = glob("images" . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

but I don't know what to do next

Comment: Either create a `recursive` function to drill down into all folders and sub-folders or, preferably, use a combination of [recursiveIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiterator.php) and [recursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a RecursiveDirectoryIterator, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

You could then do something like:

```
$folder = "path to your folder";

$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
        );

        foreach ($files as $fileinfo) {

            // fileinfo is an object, see documentation for info
            $path = $fileinfo->getRealPath();

        }
```

Comment: thank you so much, it helped me to get all files but when I want to display them I only get some blank fields like they cannot be opened

Comment: Do you mean the images don't show up in your browser? Are the images located in a folder which is accessible by your webserver? The fact that php can see contents of a folder doesn't mean your webserver allows access to that folder.

Comment: yes they don't show up. the problem appeared now, when I displayed only photos from main directory everything was okay. I gave permissions to server so folders are accessible

Comment: In your browser, check the development pane, look in the network tab, load the page. You should see errors, load failures. What error codes do you see?

Comment: so that's what I get: failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (not found)

Comment: I also noticed that my photos have type: text/html instead of jpg

Comment: If it's a 404, you need to verify the URL of the images. Is the URL really correct, pointing to the file in the subdirectory?

Comment: I think so, according to the code you sent my `$folder="./images"` and then I try to show files: `<a href="<?=$path; ?>">` `<img src="<?= $path; ?>">`

Comment: Well, the `getRealPath` function returns the full path to the file on the subdirectory (https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getrealpath.php). You need to modify that path to a path matching an URL. For example `/path/images/sub/image.jpg` should become `/images/sub/image.jpg`. So as a start strip the path to the images folder from the realPath.

Comment: ah thank you! I replaced the path to `images` with '/' and it worked for files but also for subdirectories which are shown as blank squares even though I used `!is_dir`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215478/discussion-between-maarten-veerman-and-sylwia).